# 502 Bad Gateway with nginx/1.14.0 (Ubuntu) while deploying django app on app engine

Tags: django, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have successfully deployed my app while following the tutorial on Google cloud platform for deploying django on a standard environment.

I have **mapped my custom domain** to app engine like six hours back so am not sure whether DNS propagation is not complete AND am nolonger using the default .appspot.com in **allowed hosts**, I have only my domain.
What could the issue really be? I am also using settings.py and local_settings.py

LOGS after running *gcloud app deploy*:

> UException in thread Thread-17: Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud
>   SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\bundledpython\lib\threading.py", line
>   801, in __bootstrap_inner
>       self.run()   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\bundledpython\lib\threading.py", line
>   754, in run
>       self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud
>   SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\console\progress_tracker.py",
>   line 164, in Ticker
>       if self.Tick():   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\console\progress_tracker.py",
>   line 235, in Tick
>       self._Print(self._GetSuffix())   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud
>   SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\console\progress_tracker.py",
>   line 261, in _Print
>       self._console_output.UpdateConsole()   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud
>   SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\console\multiline.py",
>   line 154, in UpdateConsole
>       self._UpdateConsole()   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\console\multiline.py",
>   line 168, in _UpdateConsole
>       self._messages[self._last_print_index].Print()   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud
>   SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\console\multiline.py",
>   line 281, in Print
>       self._WriteLine(line)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\console\multiline.py",
>   line 331, in _WriteLine
>       self._stream.write(self._level * INDENTATION_WIDTH * ' ' + line) IOError: [Errno 0] Error
>
> Updating service [default]...done. SException in thread Thread-18:
>   Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Google\Cloud
>   SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\bundledpython\lib\threading.py", line
>   801, in __bootstrap_inner
>       self.run()   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\platform\bundledpython\lib\threading.py", line
>   754, in run
>       self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud
>   SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\console\progress_tracker.py",
>   line 164, in Ticker
>       if self.Tick():   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\console\progress_tracker.py",
>   line 235, in Tick
>       self._Print(self._GetSuffix())   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud
>   SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\console\progress_tracker.py",
>   line 261, in _Print
>       self._console_output.UpdateConsole()   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud
>   SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\console\multiline.py",
>   line 154, in UpdateConsole
>       self._UpdateConsole()   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\console\multiline.py",
>   line 168, in _UpdateConsole
>       self._messages[self._last_print_index].Print()   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud
>   SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\console\multiline.py",
>   line 281, in Print
>       self._WriteLine(line)   File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Cloud SDK\google-cloud-sdk\lib\googlecloudsdk\core\console\multiline.py",
>   line 331, in _WriteLine
>       self._stream.write(self._level * INDENTATION_WIDTH * ' ' + line) IOError: [Errno 0] Error

Gunicorn:
[Could it also be Gunicorn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVx7C.png)

NB: Am using app engine for my first time thou experience has been a bad one since morning. Fixing error after error. Tutorials should be improved

Comment: 1) Use an Internet service such as MXToolbox to test/debug your DNS names. https://mxtoolbox.com/ 2) Verify that your service is responding correctly on the IP address: `curl -i --header "Host: www.your-host-name.com" http://IP-ADDRESS`.

Comment: Could you throw more light on option 2 please?

Comment: What is the question on option #2? Did you try the command, what is the result?

Comment: Download and install the CURL program. Then type (execute) the command at your command prompt. App Engine is a Google service. A proxy/load-balancer sits in front of a group/cluster of machines. These systems share IP addresses. The Host header tells the proxy which domain name it is serving. Think of a receptionist asking "who do you want to speak to?". The Host header provides that information.

Comment: 1) What command resulting in the logs? 2) Cleanup your question and format the error messages so that we can read them (use the formatting tools when posting a question).

Comment: I have formatted the error messages. Please check again

Comment: It looks like you are reporting two problems. The stack trace that you included looks like you have the Cloud SDK (gcloud) installed wrong, out of date, etc. Start by making sure that you have the latest version of Python installed, the Cloud SDK, etc.

Comment: I have done that thou 502 is still persistent. Please see this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NVx7C.png

Comment: I looked the picture. Post your source code and configuration files in your question OR create a GitHub project with your files.